# PHP bug?: MySQL (MariaDB 10.4.8) giving me "Illegal mix of collations" but columns are the same collation type

Tags: mysql, collation

**(Update: found workaround, added to bottom of original question here-- but why does workaround work/is needed?)**

I just upgraded my database to support UTF-8, and this SQL is failing when called from PHP:

`SELECT ID FROM people WHERE Email = 'myemail@example.com' AND md5(PasswordHashed) = '26Ba48f4df2dba59b00d80c4c09a90e78'`

The error message is **Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='**

The SQL works FINE when I paste it directly into the mysqld client. So I think it's something with how PHP is connecting to the database. The code to make the connection is simple:

```
$this->dbc = mysqli_connect( null, 'myuser', '', 'mytable', 0, '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' );
if ( $this->dbc ) {
    $this->dbc->set_charset( "utf8mb4" );
    $this->dbc->query( 'SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;' );
}
```

Yet it still fails. (As far as I can see, all other SQL queries in the code work fine, so this is extra weird.)

**Confirmed all is okay with existing collations:**

The collation of the database itself is utf8mb4_unicode_ci (confirmed with `SELECT @@collation_database;`)

The collation on the table itself is utf8mb4_unicode_ci (confirmed with `show table status;`)

And `show full columns from people;` confirms that:

- `Email` is varchar(70) with utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation
- `PasswordHashed` is varchar(255) with utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation
- `ID` is int(10) unsigned with no collation

My database my.cnf file has this:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

(I've also added and removed `character-set-client-handshake=FALSE` from the my.cnf file, as some other posts have mentioned. No change.)

Oddly, the error message mentions utf8mb4_**general**_ci but I can't find *anything* that is set to that collation. Everything that I can find to check is utf8mb4_unicode_ci and I've triple-checked that.

I've run `mysqlcheck` to repair the tables, and restarted the server too. I've dumped the entire table and re-imported it (thinking that rebuilding the table and its indices from scratch would help). None of this helps.

I'm running `mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.8-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

So... what is going on?!! Why am I getting this error message and why does it think something is utf8mb4_general_ci?

---

**UPDATE: found a workaround, but why?**

The code that is causing the error uses mysqli prepared statements, so it looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM people
        WHERE Email = ? AND
        MD5(PasswordHashed) = ?";

...prepare SQL...
...bind SQL parameters...
...execute()...
```

I changed it to:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM people
        WHERE Email = ? AND
        CAST(MD5(PasswordHashed) AS
             CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8mb4) = ?";
```

And now it works fine. ??!!?

So I think this is a problem with how PHP's mysqli class works with the mysql driver. As I mentioned above, the original SQL works fine when I 'prepare' it by hand and just paste it into the mysql command line... so I really don't think it had anything to do with the charset or collation at any point. I think this is some kind of weird bug where the prepared variable being inserted by the mysqli class was using a weird char set/collation.

But: also notice that the original error message was complaining about a collation, but my workaround fixed the problem by casting the character set (not the collation). Very odd.

Why did my workaround succeed? Is this documented anywhere? Is it a PHP bug?

Comment: There are two `=` in the expression.  Which one is giving you the problem?  Also, provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'col%';`

Comment: `(utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE)` and
           ` (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE)`

Those are the _same_ `CHARACTER SET` (utf8mb4), but _different_ `COLLATIONS`.

Comment: As I said above, the SQL is working fine if I paste it into the mysql daemon. It's something with how PHP's mysqli class works with the driver. I think I found a workaround -- will edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: Plz address the questions in my first comment.